# Cascading dropdowns: detecting a change made by code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

While creating cascading dropdowns I ran into a problem. Right now, the first dropdown works: When I select something from the first dropdown the second dropdown changes appropriately. However, I need to trigger another function when the second dropdown changes. I'm able create another `.change` function that triggers when the user changes the value in the second dropdown. But, the problem is that the change triggered by the user selecting the first dropdown is not detected. In other words, the change made by the code is not detected.

How could I detect both types of changes: changes made by code and changes made by a user?
Or, how can I get the first item from the second dropdown's list so that I can pass it to the common function shared by both `.change` functions.

Here is the JavaScript function I'm using to detect changes in the first dropdown and populate the second dropdown.

```
    $(function () {

    $('#Country_ID').change(function () {
        debugger;
        var id = $("#Country_ID :selected").val();
        if (id != "") {

            $.ajax({

                type: "GET",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: '@Url.Action("CityList", "DropDown")',
                data: { "mCountry": id },
                dataType: "json",
                beforeSend: function () {
                    //alert(id);
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    var items = "";
                    $.each(data, function (i, city) {
                        items += "<option value='" + city.Value + "'>" + city.Text + "</option>";
                    });
                    $('#City_ID').html(items);

                },
                error: function (result) {

                    alert('Service call failed: ' + result.status + ' Type :' + result.statusText);
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            var items = '<option value="">Select</option>';
            $('#City_ID').html(items);
        }

        @*I think I need to get the first value of the second dropdown here. 
          Then, pass the value to a function shared by the second `.change` function*@
    });
});

    $(function () {

        $('#Second_Dropdown').change(function () {
            @*call common function, passing selected value 
        });
    });
```

I'm very new to Javascript so the more detail the better.

Comment: Call `.change();` on your element to cause the event trigger.

Comment: Is very help to understand your question if you attach DEMO like: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Post the markup for the dropdowns.

Comment: I didn't think the markup was necessary in this case but I will keep it mind next time. I can see how it would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the .change() function of the second drop down after you have made the selection dynamically.
Replace:

```
$('#City_ID').html(items)
```

With:

```
$('#City_ID').html(items).change();
```